# Форма ввода данных в таблицу MySQL в PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Вопрос такой: что должно быть в цикле for, чтобы в выпадающий список записывались кафедры?

В базе данных MySQL есть две таблицы prepods и cafedrs. Таблица prepods состоит из двух полей - prepod и cafedra. cafedra также есть в таблице cafedrs, которая уже заполнена. Таблицы связаны между собой.

Нужно создать форму ввода в таблицу prepods на PHP, чтобы поле кафедра в таблице было выпадающим списком и все значения этого поля берутся из таблицы cafedrs (поле cafedra).

php-код

```
<?php
if ($_POST["submit"]) {
    if (!($connection=mysql_connect ("localhost", "root", "2357610"))) die ("Нет соединения");
    if (!(mysql_select_db ("imc", $connection))) die ("База ИМЦ не выбрана");
    $prepod=$_POST['prepod'];
    $cafedra=$_POST['cafedra'];
    if (!($cafedra=mysql_query ("SELECT cafedra from cafedrs"))) die ("Ошибка");
    $count=mysql_num_fields ($cafedra);
    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array ($cafedra)) {
        for($x=0;$x<$count;$x++) {//здесь нужно что-то сделать}
    }
    if (($cafedra!="") or ($prepod!="")) {
        $sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO prepods VALUES (null,'$prepod','$row[$x]',1)");
        $result=mysql_query($sql);
        echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\"> alert(\"Данные добавлены\");</script> \n";
    } else {
        echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\"> alert(\"Заполните поля\");</script> \n";
    };
}
?>
```

Сама форма:

```
<form action="pre.php" method="POST" name="form1">
    <table width="100%" align="center" valign=center>
        <tr>
            <td align=right>ФИО преподавателя:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="prepod">
                <br>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align=right>Наименование кафедры:</td>
            <td>
                <select name="row"></select>
                <br>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align=right>
                <br>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Сохранить">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: А в чем вопрос? Или в чем проблема?

Comment: @Ехараный Бабай, читайте выше "Нужно создать форму ввода..."© =) 

@Маша. Не думаю, что за Вас здесь кто-то что-то будет делать. Не получается что-то - обращаетесь, говорите что не получается. А "нужно сделать" это на freelance биржу вопрос. даже не вопрос, а ТЗ.

Answer (score 1):

```
    <form action="pre.php" method="POST" name="form1">
    <table width="100%" align="center" valign=center>
        <tr>
            <td align=right>ФИО преподавателя:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="prepod">
                <br>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align=right>Наименование кафедры:</td>
            <td>
                <select name="row">
                 <?
if (!($cafedra=mysql_query ("SELECT cafedra from cafedrs"))) die ("Ошибка");
    $count=mysql_num_fields ($cafedra);
    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array ($cafedra)) {
        for($x=0;$x<$count;$x++) {
         echo $row["cafedra"];
}
    }
?>

                       </select>
                <br>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align=right>
                <br>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Сохранить">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```